# ¿Qué significa circular cuando llamo al método fetch?

Tags: javascript, asincronismo, deno

Estoy llamando a una API mediante deno de la siguiente manera:

```
console.log("hola mundo");
const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
const data = await response;
console.log(data);
```

Lo corro mediante

```
deno run --allow-net holamundo.ts
```

obtengo la siguiente salida en consola

```
hola mundo
Response {
  url: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=27&type=multiple",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  type_: "default",
  trailer: Promise { <pending> },
  headers: Headers { date: Tue, 02 Jun 2020 02:36:21 GMT, server: Apache, expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT, cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalida
te, post-check=0, pre-check=0, pragma: no-cache, access-control-allow-origin: *, set-cookie: PHPSESSID=uPleMEkfU4xh5PQF2ziRb0; path=/, vary: User-Agent, strict-tr
ansport-security: max-age=31536000, transfer-encoding: chunked, content-type: application/json },
  body: Body { contentType: "application/json", locked: false, body: [Circular] },
  type: "default",
  redirected: false
}
```

¿Qué significa esa parteque dice `body:[Circular]`?

Comment: He instalado Deno 1.0 en mi Windows 10, he probado tu código, tanto con la URL que pones como con la que aparece en la respuesta y no consigo reproducir tu escenario. ¿Puedes revisar que todo es correcto?

Comment: @PabloLozano deberías de revisar, todo es correcto para mí. Me basé en este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDOZs6BMG5I

Comment: Esto es lo que veo: https://imgur.com/a/Lo40giQ

Comment: @PabloLozano tal vez sea porque usas visual studio...

Answer (score 3):

una referencia circular significa que dentro de tu respuesta json tienes algo así:

Referencia circular:

```
var parent = {
    sons: []
};
var child1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: true,
    c: 'hello',
    parent: parent
};
parent.sons.push(child1);
var child2 = {
    a: 2,
    b: false,
    c: 'bye',
    parent: parent
};
parent.sons.push(child2);
```

En este caso el objeto parent contiene una matriz con todos sus hijos (sons, y cada uno de los objetos child1 y child2 tienen una referencia a parent. En estas circunstancias, si recorremos en profundidad las propiedades, antes o después volveremos al objeto de partida, ya que existe una referencia circular.

Las referencias circulares son mucho más comunes de lo que podemos pensar a primera vista. En el DOM de los navegadores hay una gran cantidad de referencias circulares, ya que existen referencias entre unos elementos y otros.